# Issues with ListView focusing

Tags: android, listview, view, focus

In my application I have a `Fragment` that contains both a `GridView` and a `ListView` to show items using a `CursorAdapter`. Only one of these two views is enabled, the user can choose the way he wants to see the items.

So, in `onCreateView` method of my `Fragment` I have

```
gv = (GridView) v.findViewById(R.id.itemselect_gridview);
lv = (ListView) v.findViewById(R.id.itemselect_listview);
if (!UserPreferences.isViewStyleGrid(getActivity())) {
    showList();
} else {
    showGrid();
}
```

And the code of `showList` and `showGrid` is:

```
private void showList() {
    gv.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    lv.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    UserPreferences.getPreferences(getActivity()).edit()
            .putString(Constants.VIEWSTYLE, "list").commit();
}

private void showGrid() {
    lv.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    gv.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    UserPreferences.getPreferences(getActivity()).edit()
            .putString(Constants.VIEWSTYLE, "grid").commit();
}
```

When the app calls `showList`, I cannot use a d-pad (game controller) to navigate the `ListView`. Pressing the d-pad keys is not effective and only touch input works.
If the app calls `showGrid` instead, the d-pad works properly.
If I switch from grid to list at runtime, the dpad works properly also on the `ListView`, the switch is made using the same methods mentioned before. What could cause this problem? I tried to use `lv.setFocusable(true)` and `lv.requestFocus()` with no results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I realized it was too soon to call `showGrid` and `showList`, so I changed the `onCreateView` a little bit:

```
    if (UserPreferences.isViewStyleGrid(mFragment.getActivity())) {
        gv.post(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                showGrid();
            }
        });
    } else {
        lv.post(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                showList();
            }
        });
    }
```

This way both the functions are called after the views are fully initialized.